# add click event on img with data from a json (twitch api)

Tags: javascript, ajax, twitch

the problem I have is that after creating a list with images that come from the preview of specific streams, I would like to be able to click on these images and replace the stream playing with the stream that comes from the image.

In the code below I get the streamers that play GTA V and do GTA RP. With this info, I get the nickname of the players to create the url with the preview image of their stream.

...

```
     function streamData(auth){
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: 'https://api.twitch.tv/helix/search/channels? 
                      query=FailyV&live_only=true', /** gta V id = 32982 */
                
                dataType:'json',
                headers: {
                    "Client-ID": 'id',
                    "Authorization": "Bearer "+auth
                },
                success: function(streamList) { 
                     
                    for (let i = 0; i < streamList['data'].length; i++){
                        if(streamList['data'][i]['game_id'] == 32982){
                            gtaList.push(streamList['data'][i]['display_name'])                                                                                             
                            $('#twitch-embed-low').append('<img id="thumbnail'+i+' " src="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews-ttv/live_user_'+streamList['data'][i]['display_name']+'-300x200.jpg">')
                            .on("click", function(e){
                               console.log(gtaList[i])
                            })
                            }
                        }

                        new Twitch.Embed("twitch-embed-main", {
                            width: '80%',
                            height: '80%',
                            channel: gtaList[0],
                            autoplay: false,
                            layout: "video",
                            // only needed if your site is also embedded on embed.example.com and othersite.example.com 
                            parent: ["embed.example.com", "othersite.example.com"]
                        });  
                        

                        let test = $('#twitch-embed-low')
                        console.log(test[0])
                },
                error: function(data){
                    info = document.getElementById("info")
                    info.innerHTML = "ERROR: " + data["responseJSON"]["message"] + ". Make sure your CID and corresponding secret are set in the JavaScript."
                } 
            })
        }
```

...

As you can see, I have tested this

...

```
 $('#twitch-embed-low')
 .append('<img id="thumbnail'+i+' " src="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews- 
  ttv/live_user_'+streamList['data'][i]['display_name']+'-300x200.jpg">')
 .on("click", function(e){console.log(gtaList[i])})
```

...

but as you can imagine, it doesn't work (as I suspected) and each time I click on an image, it makes the complete loop and so it doesn't put the right stream in reading but systematically the last one and I'm not talking about the performances which are disastrous since it loads each stream 1 by 1.

So the idea is that when you click on the image, it puts the right stream in reading but I don't see how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a couple of improvments you can make. The first one is you are binding the click handler to the parent element and not to the `img` element, meaning it will be called `(n)` times (the length of `streamList['data']`). This is because you bind the click handler multiple times to the same html element. You want to bind this event handler just to the `img` element.

Secondly, when the event handler is called, it will be referencing the value of `i` which will always be the last value of `i` in the loop iteration. If you want to log the value of `i` at the point when you create the `img` element, you will need to use a closure to save the state of `i`, for example:

```js
var img = $('<img id="thumbnail'+i+' " src="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews- 
  ttv/live_user_'+streamList['data'][i]['display_name']+'-300x200.jpg">')
  .on("click", (function (index) {
    return function (e) {
      console.log(gtaList[index]);
    };
  })(i));

$('#twitch-embed-low').append(img)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was trying stuff and I found something like your solution but your solution is better haha. ;)

Comment: No problem. Another approach to avoid using a closure is to use data attributes to store data on the elements. Have a look at https://api.jquery.com/data/. btw can you accept the answer?

Comment: Done, sorry. It was my first question on stackoverflow, didn't have the reflex to accept the answer. ;)